# Set Destination From Bookmarks Using Dbus Navit

Tags: python, dbus, navit

By following the example here (http://wiki.navit-project.org/index.php/Talk:Dbus), I was able to zoom in and out of map in navit successfully. Is there a way to set destination for the map using saved bookmarks in a similar manner with dbus in python? I am trying to add some voice commands for set_destination,start/stop gps in navit. Any guide would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after researching a bit there was no method in navit to set destination using bookmarks using the dbus. With the help of the navit team a new extension has been created to support that. It can be found here https://github.com/navit-gps/navit/tree/dbus_bookmark. Thanks